# Download all postgresql tables to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

Is there a simple way to download all tables from a postgresql database into pandas? For example can pandas just load from the .sql file?  All the solutions I found on the line suggest connecting to the database and using select from commands, which seems far more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to a database anyway. You can find out table names from odbc cursor and then use pandas.read_table for names ex. pypyodbc finding names:

allnames=cursor.tables( schema='your_schema').fetchall()

-- without view and indexes below

tabnames=[el[2] for el in allnames if el[3]=='TABLE']